# How can i delete a file from my nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, file

I have uploaded files into a temp directory using multer

```
const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    // Destination to store image     
    destination: 'images', 
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          cb(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() 
             + path.extname(file.originalname))
             fs.writeFile("/tmp/"+file.originalname, message, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
    }
});
```

How can i remove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the file using

```
 fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err //handle your error the way you want to;
  console.log('path/file.txt was deleted');//or else the file will be deleted
    });
  );
```

Refernce : https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html